# Nested modifier ng-repeats do not respect $index?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, famo.us, angular-material

I've taken a stab at famo.us and angular lately. I like it, but I'm having issues getting my sidenav working the way I want.

[image: Sidenav menu items with sub menu item]

When I click any of the Test1-3 menu items, I want child menu items to slide open from beneath them. I have not yet implemented any sliding, as my current problem is that no children seem to respect the fa-index of the layout.

Update: The children load and unload just fine, it's just that they always appear at the bottom of the menu items, rather than beneath them. Am I doing something wrong with the fa-modify tags? If I was working in angular I'm pretty sure my ng-repeats would work as expected with this setup.

```
                <fa-app>
                    @*<fa-grid-layout fa-options="myGridLayoutOptions">*@
                    <fa-sequential-layout fa-options="navCtrl.sequentialOptions">
                        <fa-modifier ng-repeat="item in admin" fa-size="[true, true]" @*fa-size="[true, undefined]"*@ @*fa-proportions="[1, 1]"*@>
                            <fa-surface>
                                <md-list-item ng-click="navCtrl.toggleMenuExpand($index)" @*ng-click="go(item.link)"*@>
                                    <a>
                                        <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row">
                                            <div class="inset">
                                                <ng-md-icon icon="{{item.icon}}"></ng-md-icon>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="inset">
                                                {{item.title + " " + $index}}
                                            </div>
                                        </md-item-content>
                                    </a>
                                </md-list-item>
                            </fa-surface>

                            <fa-modifier ng-if="item.active" ng-repeat="submenuItem in item.submenu">
                                <fa-surface fa-index="1">
                                    <md-list-item ng-click="go(submenuItem.link)">
                                        <a>
                                            <md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row">
                                                <div class="inset">
                                                    <ng-md-icon icon="{{submenuItem.icon}}"></ng-md-icon>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="inset">
                                                    {{submenuItem.title + " " + $index}}
                                                </div>
                                            </md-item-content>
                                        </a>
                                    </md-list-item>
                                </fa-surface>
                            </fa-modifier>
                        </fa-modifier>
                    </fa-sequential-layout>
                    @*</fa-grid-layout>*@
                </fa-app>
```

How would I properly make it so that any children appear correctly underneath each menu item?

Here is the array of each menu item, just to clarify.

```
var adminmenus = [
{
    link: '/overview',
    title: 'Test1',
    icon: 'settings',
    active: true,
    submenu: [{ link: '/overview', title: 'Test1SubTest1', icon: 'settings', active: false }]
},
{
    link: '/overview',
    title: 'Test2',
    icon: 'settings',
    active: false,
    submenu: [{ link: '/overview', title: 'Test2SubTest1', icon: 'settings', active: false }]
},
{
    link: '/handover',
    title: 'Test3',
    icon: 'attach_money',
    active: false,
    submenu: [{ link: '/overview', title: 'Test3SubTest1', icon: 'settings', active: false }]
}
];
```

**Update:** Am I perhaps looking at the famo.us implementation in the wrong way? I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898895/surface-selection-in-famo-us-angular), wondering if I should generate the menu with the appropriate sub menus from the controller instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long story short, this feature is most likely not implemented in the famous/angular integration, simply.

I am leaving this attempt due to that famo.us is doing a major rework of their engine, whereas famous/angular is left in the dust. For anyone reading, I advise looking into famo.us and angular again in a year when their new engine has been developed on well enough.

[This (somewhat hidden) announcement](https://github.com/Famous/famous-angular/issues/372#issuecomment-108714063) is from Zack Brown from famo.us.

> **The future of Famo.us/Angular**
>
> I can give some insight in the future of Famous in relation to
>   AngularJS, and the path we've taken to arriving at this decision.
>
> Famo.us/Angular is an integration library. Its roots extend deeply
>   into both of the integrated libraries (Famo.us 0.3 and Angular 1.x)
>   and its implementation is very specific to the idiosyncrasies of those
>   two libraries. Some example integrations:
>
> patching into Angular's animation and lifecycle system to trigger and
>   handle Famo.us animations patching into Angular's directive
>   compilation system to build the Famo.us render tree in the first place
>   creating directives that allow Famo.us event piping into the
>   underlying Famo.us render nodes supporting Angular's event pipeline
>   (e.g. ng-click on top of Famo.us Surfaces) supporting ng-repeating
>   elements into a Famo.us Scrollview or GridLayout handling cases like
>   ng-show and ng-if in Famo.us making the whole thing perform well
>   within the constraints of Angular's digest cycle. etc. And these are
>   just a few of the many adventures that we encountered while building
>   Famo.us/Angular. Now let's bring four different libraries into the
>   mix:
>
> Famo.us 0.3 Famous Engine, a.k.a. "mixed mode," a.k.a. 0.5.0 Angular
>   1.x Angular 2 To fully support integrations between {Famo.us 0.3, Famous Engine}x{Angular 1.x, Angular 2} would require four completely
>   distinct integration libraries. Obviously, this isn't tenable.
>
> Famo.us 0.3 is deprecated. Thus, we can rule out integrating it with
>   Angular 2. The question then becomes: should we write an integration
>   between Engine and Angular 1.x, or Engine and Angular 2, or both?
>   While we're at it, should we build an integration with React? With
>   Ember? With Backbone? Mithril? FOAM?
>   Insert-JavaScript-Framework-Du-Jour?
>
> The answer is, we absolutely plan to support all of these, but we
>   don't want to (and can't afford to) write a from-the-ground-up
>   integration with all of them.
>
> So what's the trick?
>
> If we do our job right, no one will have to write a heavy-weight
>   integration like this again.
>
> We (at Famous) have to write "one integration to support them all" —
>   we don't want to integrate Famous Engine with AngularJS; we want to
>   integrate Famous Engine with web authoring standards in such a way
>   that using Famous with, say, Angular or React—or even just
>   Bootstrap—is simple. The good news: we're already writing it. It's our
>   Framework Layer. (oh, and that's why Engine is called Engine—it's one
>   of two layers of the Famous Project: Engine and Framework.)
>
> What does this Framework look like?
>
> It supports HTML as an authoring language. This is key, as it allows
>   mixing in other applications/frameworks both inside and outside of the
>   Famous render tree.
>
> It exposes very clear, simple-to-use interfaces for manipulating
>   Famous components. This allows for logic from any other
>   application/framework to interact with Famous in a consistent,
>   predictable, and extensible way.
>
> It supports passing through to raw Famous Engine anywhere it's needed.
>
> It supports passing into and out of Famous or HTML flexibly, and
>   allows easily working with CSS and other assets (images, fonts, other
>   media.)
>
> In other words: writing an Angular integration with the Framework will
>   be loads simpler than writing it with straight-up Engine. I strongly
>   encourage anyone who's interested in an Angular<>Famous integration to
>   wait for the rest of Famous, i.e. the Framework, to be released.
>
> When is that?
>
> As of now (June 2015) Framework is still in Private Beta. We are
>   inviting anyone who's interested and who can make it to come on site
>   in SF to work with us in Famous Labs to test-drive the Framework and
>   get/give feedback directly with the Framework team.
>
> We will be making an announcement about Framework at jQuerySF toward
>   the end of June. It's very possible we will release our Public Beta on
>   that date.
>
> You can reach me at zack@famo.us if you're interested in the Private
>   Beta or more information.